# Jira automation to alert when hours differ from original estimate

Tags: jira, jira-automation

I've been trying to build a jira automation on cloud jira which would notify on slack when the time remaining on the ticket is 40% or less of the original estimate. This would trigger a slack message.

Slack webhook seems to be working fine but the time check doesn't seem to trigger.

For the automation to trigger when ticket time remaining goes below 40% of original estimate notification be sent to the slack channel that I've set.

edit:

Solution is attached as the picture. for some reason the system is not allowing me ot add it.

[in this picture is solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cxW2.png)